# How to parse json with object and List for the same attribute? C#

Tags: json, parsing

On trying to parse JSON, I got an error about types. I have this code:

```
public class Event
{

    [JsonProperty("eventKey")]
    public int EventKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("displayOrder")]
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subTypeKey")]
    public int SubTypeKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("eventName")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("eventNameTranslated")]
    public string EventNameTranslated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("eventStatus")]
    public string EventStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("eventSort")]
    public string EventSort { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("eventDateTime")]
    public DateTime EventDateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("classSortCode")]
    public string ClassSortCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("typeFlagCode")]
    public string TypeFlagCode { get; set; }
}

public class Events
{

    [JsonProperty("num")]
    public int Num { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("event")]
    public IList<Event> Event { get; set; }
}

public class Subtype
{

    [JsonProperty("subTypeKey")]
    public int SubTypeKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subTypeName")]
    public string SubTypeName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("displayOrder")]
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("events")]
    public Events Events { get; set; }
}

public class Subtypes
{

    [JsonProperty("num")]
    public int Num { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subtype")]
    public Subtype Subtype { get; set; }
}
```

But I am getting error, because it can't parse it, cause sometimes it have type as List, sometimes as object. See screenshot (subtype and event).
How can I change my code to support different types?

[image: json file]

Can you help me with this? Or what I need to read, to solve my problem?

Comment: Answer would depend on what programming language you are using, no?

Comment: Hello. Yes, i am sorry, c#